# ASP MVC RTM on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I use the ASP MVC 4 Beta with VS 2010, when the RTM comes out will I be able to use it with VS 2010, i.e not be forced to upgrade to VS 11?

Answer (score 1):

When released ASP.NET MVC 4 will be available for VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody knows for sure, but I would say yes, however there may be tools in the RTM that will not be available in the 2010 release.  Feature wise I can't see any issues.